# Human and alien stranded on a barren world. Initially enemies but come to respect each other

Tags: story-identification

The movie is about a human and an alien being stranded together on a barren world. They initially hate each other, but grow to respect each other.

I remember the quote

> *I need to look at a face.  Even a face as oogly* [how the alien  pronounced ugly] *as yours.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [Enemy Mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_Mine_(film)).

> *You saved my life.*
>
> *Why?*
>
> *Maybe...I need to look at another face even as ugly as yours.*

Comment: The book was better than the movie (they virtually always are, right?).

Comment: Are you real Valorum?  I am legit starting to think you may actually be a robot.  Please note that I mean that as the highest of compliments.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster - **Error 406: [Humility Not Found](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/79/e8/be/79e8beb6bcdf68a17fd3cfff63a379ec.png).**

Comment: @ZeissIkon - I liked the film better.

Comment: @Valorum Better than what, the original novella, or the novelization?

Comment: I am watching a legal version of it now (it's amazing how fast Amazon delivers isn't it?) and I have to say, the make-up and prosthetics are fantastic.

Comment: Also, I just realized something.  Denis Quaid has a habit of befriending dragons.